# Partition a matrix into several matrices

Tags: matlab

How can I partition a matrix into several smaller matrices to find unknown variables?

For example, given:

[image: new new image]

how can solve this problem by partitioning (splitting) a matrix 3x3 into smaller matrices (1x1 or other) to find the values of x, y, z and u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *new* image, you isolate for the unknown matrix using some identities:

```
A * X = B
(inv(A)) * A * X = (inv(A)) * B
I * X = (inv(A)) * B
X = (inv(A)) * B
```

In Matlab:

```
A = [1, 2; 0, 1]
B = [4, 7; 4, 6]
X = inv(A) * B
```

Output:

```
ans =

    -4    -5
     4     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix dimensions dont agree, or am I missing something?

Edit:
The code from Jeff E will work fine on smaller matrices.
For bigger matrices you will need to use backward substitution or some other algorithm, mainly because matrix inversion is a memory intensive task.

Comment: this matrix is for example . how can split this matrix to small matrix for find x and y

Comment: Are you looking for [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)? The equation in the picture you posted is nonsense, and you wouldn't use "matrix splitting" anyway to solve a problem like that.

Comment: i does not understand this article.please write a sample and find x and y

Comment: It's impossible to find x and y because the equation *makes no sense*. You can't multiply a 3x3 matrix by a 3x1 matrix and get a 3x3 matrix out of it.

Comment: for example 2*3 matrix out of it

Comment: No. Read up on [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29). A 3x3 matrix multiplied by a 3x1 matrix can only give you a 3x1 matrix.

Comment: The link is broken, try it again.

Answer (score 0):

To solve an equation of the form A*X=B, you should use the [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html), since explicitly taking the inverse [should be avoided if possible](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/)

```
A = [1, 2; 0, 1];
B = [4, 7; 4, 6];
X = A\B
X =

    -4    -5
     4     6
```